# How to stop music from playing when user switch to other page in Android Studio Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-music-player

I have created a meditation application that users can select the class they want from the recycler view within the fragment, then it will show the detailed content and steps in a new activity. In the new activity, I have implemented a audio playing functions where user can stream the audio file from the firebase. The problem now is whenever I switch back to the recycler view within the fragment, the audio file still plays in the background. How do I stop the audio file from playing whenever I switch to another page within the app or switch to another app ?

This is the code for the recycler view within the fragment

```
class ClassFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var classArrayList: ArrayList<Classes>
private lateinit var tempArraylist: ArrayList<Classes>
private lateinit var classAdapter: ClassAdapter
private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_class, container, false)
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.ClassList)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

    classArrayList = arrayListOf()
    tempArraylist = arrayListOf()
    eventChangeListener()
    classAdapter = ClassAdapter(requireContext(), classArrayList)

    recyclerView.adapter = classAdapter

    return view
}


private fun eventChangeListener() {
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    db.collection("class").addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
        override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
            if (error != null) {
                Log.e("Firestore error", error.message.toString())
                return
            }
            for (dc: DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!) {
                if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                    classArrayList.add(
                        dc.document.toObject(
                            (Classes::class.java)
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
            tempArraylist.clear()
            tempArraylist.addAll(classArrayList)
            classAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    })
}
```

}

This is the code for the new activity page where it will show content when the user selects from recyclerview

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var imageViewClass: ImageView
private lateinit var textViewClassName: TextView
private lateinit var textViewClassDes: TextView
private lateinit var textViewClassContent: TextView
private var stop:Boolean = false
var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)
    val btnPlay: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnPlay)
    val btnStop: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnStop)


    imageViewClass = findViewById(R.id.imageViewClassImage)
    textViewClassName = findViewById(R.id.textViewClassName)
    textViewClassDes = findViewById(R.id.textViewClassDescription)
    textViewClassContent = findViewById(R.id.textViewClassContent)


    val classImage = intent.getStringExtra("class_image")
    val className = intent.getStringExtra("class_name")
    val classDes = intent.getStringExtra("class_des")
    val classContent = intent.getStringExtra("class_content")
    val classAudio = intent.getStringExtra("class_audio")

    Glide.with(this)
        .load(classImage)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(imageViewClass)
    textViewClassName.text = className
    textViewClassDes.text = classDes
    textViewClassDes.text = classDes!!.replace("\\n", "\n")
    textViewClassContent.text = classContent
    textViewClassContent.text = classContent!!.replace("\\n", "\n")

    btnPlay.isEnabled = true
    btnStop.isEnabled = false

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this@DetailActivity, Uri.parse(classAudio))
                mediaPlayer!!.isLooping = true
                mediaPlayer!!.start()
                btnStop.isEnabled = true
                btnPlay.isEnabled = false
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Audio Starts",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else mediaPlayer!!.start()

        }

    })

    mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener {
        btnPlay.isEnabled = true
        btnStop.isEnabled = false
        Toast.makeText(this,"end",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            if(mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying){
                stop = false
                mediaPlayer!!.stop()
                mediaPlayer!!.reset()
                mediaPlayer!!.release()
                mediaPlayer = null
                btnPlay.isEnabled = true
                btnStop.isEnabled = false
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Audio Stops",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case of `onDestroy` of the `Activity` being called. I'll keep it short but there is a lifecycle through which an `Activity` undergoes and when you seem to come back from the SecondActivity to the first Activity, the `onDestroy` of your second activity is called to perform the destruction function

So the solution, override the `onDestroy` method in your `DetailActivity` class and do something like this

```
override fun onDestroy(){
 if(mediaPlayer != null){
   mediaPlayer!!.stop()
   mediaPlayer!!.reset()
   mediaPlayer!!.release()
   mediaPlayer = null
 }
}
```

You can read in detail about [Activity Lifecyle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)